# HDFS block size choice

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, distributed-computing

3 machines (1 master), 44 MB file.

1. If HDFS block size = 32 MB, the file will be divided into two blocks: 32 MB and 12 MB.

Does this mean one slave can process 32 MB and the other can process 12 MB parallelly?

2. If HDFS block size = 16 MB, the file would be divided into three blocks: 16 MB, 16MB and 12 MB.

Does this mean one slave can process 16 MB, the other can process the other 16 MB and they finish at the same time, then, one of them will process 12 MB? **Thus, does this make this block size choice better?**

Comment: The block size is always that, never smaller. You'll need larger memory on the namenode to maintain more blocks, by the way. But you seem to understand the basics, so did you try it? What did you observe?

Comment: For a 12MB file, HDFS block size = 8MB results the best. (comparing to block sizes 2MB and 4MB) I might be completely wrong, but this is how I see it: with 8MB the file is split into 8 and 4. Resulting in 4MBs of waiting. With 4MB; 4 4 4. Actually again, 4MBs of waiting but the division brings overhead. With 2MB; 2 2 2 2 2 2. No waiting at all but the division is just too much.

Comment: Honestly, if you're processing such small files, my opinion is that you don't need Hadoop. For example https://aadrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html